# Insert space before middle initial name

Tags: excel, formula

In column A I have a list of names. For example in cell A1 I have:

```
Johnson,BenE.
```

The "E." is the middle initial part of the name. I needed to insert a space so that it looks like

```
Johnson,Ben E.
```

I can't seem to figure out the proper formula for it.

Answer (score 1):

And, to make use of a rarely used function:

```
=REPLACE(A1,LEN(A1)-1,0," ")
```

Answer (score 0):

=LEFT(A1,SEARCH(".",A1)-2) &" " & RIGHT(A1,2)

Got it!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the middle initial is always one letter followed by a period

```
=LEFT(A1,LEN(A1)-2)&' '&RIGHT(A1,2)
```